# Bash whois script calling local information with *?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm getting a very strange output from a script. Here is the line run in the terminal by itself:

```
root@KaliTestBox:~/Desktop/dns1# echo $(whois 13.66.39.88 |head -n 40 |tail -n 28 |tr '\n' ' ')
```

But the output is running a "ls" somehow? Using block quotes as I removed newlines to use in a CSV. Everything is bold is a "ls" run twice? I don't understand. The actual whois is below it.

EDIT: looking at this it's something to do with the *, but that doesn't work just put into the command line? I'm still posting and changing the title: why does the star in the script dump the directory contents? Isn't this kind of thing a security risk?

```
> root@KaliTestBox:~/Desktop/dns1# echo $(whois 13.66.39.88 |head -n 40 |tail -n 28 |tr '\n' ' ')
```

`NetRange: 13.64.0.0 - 13.107.255.255 CIDR: 13.96.0.0/13, 13.104.0.0/14, 13.64.0.0/11 NetName: MSFT NetHandle: NET-13-64-0-0-1 Parent: NET13 (NET-13-0-0-0-0) NetType: Direct Assignment OriginAS: Organization: Microsoft Corporation (MSFT) RegDate: 2015-03-26 Updated: 2015-03-26 Ref: https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/13.64.0.0 OrgName: Microsoft Corporation OrgId: MSFT Address: One Microsoft Way City: Redmond StateProv: WA PostalCode: 98052 Country: US RegDate: 1998-07-09 Updated: 2017-01-28 Comment: To report suspected security issues specific to traffic emanating from Microsoft online services, including the distribution of malicious content or other illicit or illegal material through a Microsoft online service, please submit reports to: Comment: **Akamai Akamai1 Akamai DNS.rtf Akamai_hosts_4-30.txt Akamai_hosts_cleaned complete-domainlist-4-30.txt dns2 dnschecker.sh dnsCSV dnsCSV1 dnsCSV.7z dnsCSVexternal dnsCSVfail DNS Exp1.7z dnsExport2.7z dnsExternal1.txt dnslist1 dnslistProd DNSlist.txt exeternalNmap1.txt externalNmapOutput externalNmapProd ipsExternal1.txt ipsExternal2.txt LVSIDEV.txt LVSIP.txt LVSIRED.txt LVS.txt LV_Website_Management.xlsx MarkMon_12-27-2018.xls prodAkamai1Url prodAkamaiUrl1 rvCSV rvCSVerror rvdns.sh test test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 whoischeck.sh whoisCSV whoisCSV3-25** https://cert.microsoft.com. Comment: Comment: For SPAM and other abuse issues, such as Microsoft Accounts, please contact: Comment: **Akamai Akamai1 Akamai DNS.rtf Akamai_hosts_4-30.txt Akamai_hosts_cleaned complete-domainlist-4-30.txt dns2 dnschecker.sh dnsCSV dnsCSV1 dnsCSV.7z dnsCSVexternal dnsCSVfail DNS Exp1.7z dnsExport2.7z dnsExternal1.txt dnslist1 dnslistProd DNSlist.txt exeternalNmap1.txt externalNmapOutput externalNmapProd ipsExternal1.txt ipsExternal2.txt LVSIDEV.txt LVSIP.txt LVSIRED.txt LVS.txt LV_Website_Management.xlsx MarkMon_12-27-2018.xls prodAkamai1Url prodAkamaiUrl1 rvCSV rvCSVerror rvdns.sh test test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 whoischeck.sh whoisCSV whoisCSV3-25** abuse@microsoft.com.`

whois output:

```
#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/tou/
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/inaccuracy_reporting/
#
# Copyright 1997-2019, American Registry for Internet Numbers, Ltd.
#


NetRange:       13.64.0.0 - 13.107.255.255
CIDR:           13.104.0.0/14, 13.64.0.0/11, 13.96.0.0/13
NetName:        MSFT
NetHandle:      NET-13-64-0-0-1
Parent:         NET13 (NET-13-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Assignment
OriginAS:       
Organization:   Microsoft Corporation (MSFT)
RegDate:        2015-03-26
Updated:        2015-03-26
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/13.64.0.0



OrgName:        Microsoft Corporation
OrgId:          MSFT
Address:        One Microsoft Way
City:           Redmond
StateProv:      WA
PostalCode:     98052
Country:        US
RegDate:        1998-07-09
Updated:        2017-01-28
Comment:        To report suspected security issues specific to traffic emanating from Microsoft online services, including the distribution of malicious content or other illicit or illegal material through a Microsoft online service, please submit reports to:
Comment:        * https://cert.microsoft.com.  
Comment:        
Comment:        For SPAM and other abuse issues, such as Microsoft Accounts, please contact:
Comment:        * abuse@microsoft.com.  
Comment:        
Comment:        To report security vulnerabilities in Microsoft products and services, please contact:
Comment:        * secure@microsoft.com.  
Comment:        
Comment:        For legal and law enforcement-related requests, please contact:
Comment:        * msndcc@microsoft.com
Comment:        
Comment:        For routing, peering or DNS issues, please 
Comment:        contact:
Comment:        * IOC@microsoft.com
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/MSFT


OrgAbuseHandle: MAC74-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Microsoft Abuse Contact
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-425-882-8080 
OrgAbuseEmail:  abuse@microsoft.com
OrgAbuseRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/MAC74-ARIN

OrgTechHandle: MRPD-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Microsoft Routing, Peering, and DNS
OrgTechPhone:  +1-425-882-8080 
OrgTechEmail:  IOC@microsoft.com
OrgTechRef:    https://rdap.arin.net/registry/entity/MRPD-ARIN


#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/tou/
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/resources/registry/whois/inaccuracy_reporting/
#
# Copyright 1997-2019, American Registry for Internet Numbers, Ltd.
```

Comment: Double-quote the command substitution, or better yet don't use `echo` and `$()` like this (they mostly cancel each other out)l just run the command directly. BTW, this is a near-duplicate of: [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary/) (that concerns variable substitution, but the same thing applies to command substitution).

Comment: If you check the `Ref:` link from the whois output you will see that you can obtain the same data from arin.net in json format which you can extract and format in proper .csv with `jq`, instead of trying to "parse" it with `$(whois | head | tail | tr)`. You can even bulk download the whole data

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `echo $(somecommand)` to see the output of `somecommand`.  Just `somecommand` is enough.  You don't usually use `echo` to see the output of other commands, and you don't need it here either.

What is also happening in your case is that you are using the command substitution (the `$(...)` bit) unquoted.  When you do this, two things happens:

1. The shell splits the result of the expansion (the output of your pipeline) into *words* based on the contents of `$IFS`.  By default, this means that each whitespace-separated string will become one word.
2. Each word generated in the word-splitting stage undergoes filename generation ("globbing").  This means that if a word is a valid filename pattern, like `*` (which occurs a number of times in the `whois` output), then the shell will try to match it against the filenames available in the filesystem.

This means that you will get the same effect as if you did

```
echo *
```

But the main point here is that you don't need `echo` to see the output of your pipeline at all.  Just remove the `echo` and the `$(...)`:

```
whois 13.66.39.88 | head -n 40 | tail -n 28 | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: Ok so this is helpful. I'm not sure why you keep highlighting I don't need to use the command sub. If I didn't; it wouldn't show the result I'm talking about. I have to use it in my script because I'm checking it inside another function. Thank you for explanation of *